# Stackoverflow is Slashdotted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Just wanted to inform you all that SO is featured on [Slashdot](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/09/09/27/2127259/StackOverflow-For-Any-Topic) today after Jon Skeet reached 100K:

> *"StackOverflow, the successful question-and-answer website for programmers, is now over a year old and its top user has just passed 100,000 reputation points. Now one of the creators of StackOverflow, Joel Spolsky, and his company Fog Creek, are developing a software-as-a-service form of the StackOverflow engine called StackExchange to support any topic you want. The software is currently in private beta, but the first few beta sites have surfaced. Topics include business travel, the home, parenthood, the environment, finance, and iPhone game development."*

Nice.

Comment: What happened to /.? They used to be newsy. Now it's a little oldsy.

Comment: The year of the linux desktop failed to arrive.

Comment: It will arrive next year, I promise.

Comment: I thought the year of the linux desktop was when my mother didn't scream at me because the computer "worked funny". Now the computer just "works" (tm).

Comment: "Slashdot: Yesterday's News Tomorrow."

Answer (score 11):

I doesn't seem "slashdotted" to me in the normal sense of the term, i.e. the website being overloaded. It's working fine for me. Maybe that's just my direct brain-to-database connection though :)

I'd also say the story is more to do with StackExchange than my reputation, amusing as it is to have a direct link to my user profile :)

Comment: Aren't you using the TCP to connect to SO ? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep/560#560

Comment: Hey, wait! You connect directly to the database with your brain? All Jeff game me was a cerebral connection to the UI so that I could type without hands. Once again we post-human users are given the short stick while the favourites like Jon "sleeping is for noobs" Skeet get all the perks. It's unfair, and if I still had lungs I would be yelling about it.

Answer (score 9):

What would happen if Slashdot was StackOverflowed?

Comment: What it does mean?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding what random commented: Slashdot sure seems to have passed its golden age, or the peak of the hype cycle, or whatever. (So yeah, SO will hardly be "[slashdotted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect)" that way.)

But in my view it still qualifies as a "reliable third-party publication", so the post will be another good source for the [Wikipedia entry on Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow). Which is nice - perhaps we might finally throw that `{{primarysources}}` warning away (with good conscience) :)